# Cannot install or try ubuntu

Tags: boot, mount, 22.04, uefi

I was trying to switch to Ubuntu, but when I try to press any option in the grub panel, the same message always appears:

```
0.097760] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

1.619490] usbhid 1-9:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter
'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) stdin: Invalid argument

mount: mounting /dev/100p11 on /minimal.enhanced-secureboot.squashfs
failed: Invalid argument

Can not mount /dev/loop11
(/cdrom/casper/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.squashfs) on
/minimal.enhanced-secureboot.squashfs
```

I tried to do it on a different computer, with almost the same components, and it worked correctly on that computer, and I already tried with different pendrives

Specs:

- Currently OS: Windows 11
- Motherboard: B460m r.2
- CPU: I3-10105f
- GPU: Intel Iris Xe (Asus DG1)
- RAM: 16gb DDR4 2666mhz

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and built it with Rufus, which followed the instructions on the Ubuntu page and left all the options as they are by default

I had also tried with unetbooting and in this case the grub menu did not appear directly.

Update: I was able to install it, I redid the pendrive but this time with Ubuntu 23.10.1 and balenaEtcher, I can't say what the problem was exactly, but if anyone runs into the same thing, that was my solution.

Comment: Also, it says that I do not have SGX activated from the BIOS, but I do

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The comments are our channel to ask you for clarifications. Please [edit your question](https://askubutu.com/posts/1502150/edit), or click the word **Edit** below your question and add new information in your question. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include some details about the hardware you are trying to install Ubuntu onto? A little bit of specificity goes a long way towards diagnosing a remote problem 

Comment: Please put solutions in the answer section, not as an edit to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using Rufus or Unetbooting, i use balenaEtcher following the steps in https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick
And also downloaded the Ubuntu 23.10.01 instead of LTS version 22.04

Update: Confirm that it was that balenaEtcher is the solution